# Events: Key not found "Parameter name" in collection

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, byval

Conside the following method:

```
Protected Sub DoSomethingStupid(ByVal r As UltraGridRow, ByVal action As String)


    If action.equals("Go") Then
        'item_id still exists in r.Cells
        RaiseEvent BeginGoAction(action, New GoActionEventArgs(Me.Scope, r.Cells("item_id").Value.ToString))
    End If

    'Error Occurs Here: item_id & item_type don't exist anymore in r.Cells
    StartMyWorkFlow(r.Cells("item_id").Value.ToString, CStr(r.Cells("item_type").Value))
End Sub
```

**Flow**:

1)
If `action == "Go"` then the program should use `r.Cells("item_id")` (example = "000123456") to create an set of arguments (`GoActionEventArgs`) to pass along to my event (`BeginGoAction`). Right until this point `r.Cells("item_id")` still exists and contains values.

```
    If action.equals("Go") Then
        RaiseEvent BeginGoAction(action, New GoActionEventArgs(Me.Scope, r.Cells("item_id").Value.ToString))
    End If
```

2)
After the event is being fired and all actions linked to this event are executed then the program should start a workflow. Allowing the action to be completed across different applications. therefor it needs `item_id` and `item_type` stored in my `r.Cells`. Except all of sudden `R.Cells.Count() = 0` and it no longer contains `item_id` and `item_type`

```
StartMyWorkFlow(r.Cells("item_id").Value.ToString, CStr(r.Cells("item_type").Value))
```

**Question:**
How can `r.Cells` change from containing values (`item_id`,`item_type`,...) to being an empty collection just because of an event being fired? As the event has no influence on `r.Cells` or the grid in which `r` resides.

**Note** this is psuedo code based on existing code. Please forgive me for any typos...

**Note 2:** The event does **not** clear (or have any interaction with) the grid . It performs a set of delicate actions to different webservices/databases. The code of which is too long (all methods combined) to post here.

**Extra Info:**

Constructor GoActionEventArgs:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal scope As EventScope, ByVal item_id As String)
    MyBase.New(scope, item_id )
End Sub
```

Event BeginGoAction:

```
Public Event BeginGoAction(ByVal actionName As String, ByVal args As GoActionEventArgs)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a proper explanation of what you expect to happen and what actually does happen rather then expecting us to work it out from incomplete, undocumented code that doesn't actually do what you want.

Comment: Thnx for the pointer: I've updated more information about the flow and the actual cause of the error

Comment: So maybe the eventhandler clears the Grid? There still is no relevant code in the question.

Comment: Posting all the code contained and executed due to the event would make this impossible to read. The question is how can a parameter (given as byval and not linked to anything else) suddenly lose all its  values?

Comment: So when `StartMyWorkFlow(r.Cells("item_id")...)` works *if you don't* raise the event; and it *does not work* when you raise the event, then the problem is clearly inside one of the event handlers.

Comment: That is the part i don't understand. The Eventhandler never recieves ´r´nor does it have any communication with grid. Even still how can it adjust a methodparameter without have access to it?